# Loading HTML forms through php then using JQuery to submit forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a dilema which I'm unsure how to approach right now. I know that JQuery needs to have a unique set of ID's to be called in the document ready function. I go through PHP and read my mysql table to print out these HTML forms and with each form is a button that will add a new item to this table.

The issue here is that I cannot have an idea of how many forms there will be so I would like to write the JQuery code so that it can dynamically read anytime that the button is clicked, but know which button was clicked so that the proper ID's can pass.

I've seen some examples but they have more to do with CSS styling, are there any ideas or thoughts as to how this problem could be remedied?

Comment: It sounds like you should use a class here instead of assigning a unique id to each element. You can then use jQuery to execute a function when the button is clicked.

Comment: @thatidiotguy so when you mention adding a class instead of assigning a unique id, do you mean adding a class similar to the way a CSS class is referenced? and how would that class we referenced in the JQuery? So far I have something similar to this:

Comment: $(".editFeature").click(function(elem){
   var idFeat = $(elem).attr("id");
   alert(id);
  });

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am talking about. Use the class to attach the event, and then get the id in the function. Just so you know you can just do `elem.id` to get the id of the element. It is unnecessary to jqueryify the object.

Comment: @thatidiotguy See the only issue here is that I want to get the specific form, and I want to do that during a click event in jquery. What would be best practice here, should I attach a class to the form and call a .click function on the form (in doing so how could I obtain the values of THAT form?) or is there a better practice method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing out the forms in a for loop with php you can assign each submit button an id using the iterator, like submit_1, submit_2 etc and then you can have an on click handler in jquery using a selector contains, something like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[id*="submit_"]', function() {
    //code goes here
    alert( $(this).prop('id') );
});
```

Comment: do you have a website link to the proper syntax for using the id?

Comment: what do you mean by proper syntax for using the id?

Comment: So if I follow this code as a base with a click function where my input id=*"something_" it only makes the first item in input[id*="something_" clickable the rest are unable to be clicked, but even the first item that is clickable won't get the id of the button on click.

Comment: this code will alert the id of any input with an id that contains "submit_" on the page. You can then do whatever you need using that id. Here is a simple example of the forms: `<form action="" method="get" name="form_1"><input name="field1" type="text"><input id="submit_1" name="submit_1" type="submit" value="submit"></form>
<form action="" method="get" name="form_2"><input name="field1" type="text"><input id="submit_2" name="submit_2" type="submit" value="submit"></form>`

Comment: I think the reason that this method isn't working is because the forms are getting dynamically generated. For example: I have a dropdown that loads and once that dropdown is changed it executes the php which fills up the fields with the forms and inputs in the form that I need to acquire. Is there a similar solution or idea you may have that can solve this issue?

Comment: the forms being dynamically generated should have nothing to do with it. Do you have some sample code that the php generates?

Comment: I realized that the issue was that it was using a span instead of a submit button. That fixed the issue; however, if I have a form like you have in your example, how do I get the value of something such as input id=variable1 which is inside of that form with the same document.on click function? Also thanks so much for your help so far, it's turned out to be very valuable!

Comment: Once you are inside that click function and have the id, you can loop through all the inputs that are attached to the form with that id. Code something like this in the click function: `id = $(this).prop('id');$("#form_"+id+" input[type=text]").each(function() {alert( $(this).val() );
            });` This is completely untested but I'm sure you get the direction.